# Failed to send image from one activity to another. Please see details

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm fetching user's profile picture from facebook and I want to send it to `ProfileActivity.java` so that it can be displayed on user profile.

The problem is that the image is not getting sent from `SignUpScreen.java` to `ProfileActivity.java`. Though I am able to send name & email from one to another.

Here's `SignUpScreen.java` file's code:

```
public class SignUpScreen extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Button facebookLoginButton;
    CircleImageView mProfileImage;
    TextView mUsername, mEmailID;
    Profile mFbProfile;
    ParseUser user;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    public String name, email, userID;
    public static final List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("public_profile");
        add("email");
    }};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_sign_up_screen);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Pac.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);

        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);
        mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        mEmailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutUser);

        mFbProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        //mUsername.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //mEmailID.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        facebookLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
        facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(SignUpScreen.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                        } else if (user.isNew()) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                            getUserDetailsFromFacebook();
                            final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                            handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    saveNewUser();
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

    public void saveNewUser() {
        user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword("hidden");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "SignUp Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "SignUp Unsuccesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("error when signingup", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getUserDetailsFromFacebook() {

        final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        //Log.d("response", "response" + object.toString());
                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(SignUpScreen.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        try {
                            name = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                            mUsername.setText(name);
                            email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                            mEmailID.setText(email);
                            userID = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                            new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID);

                            b.putString("userName", name);
                            b.putString("userEmail", email);

                            profileIntent.putExtras(b);
                            profileIntent.putExtra("user_pic", bmp);
                            startActivity(profileIntent);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name, email, id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    class ProfilePicAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String imageURL;
            String id = userID;
            imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ id +"/picture?type=large";
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Loading picture failed", e.toString());

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

    }
}
```

Here's `ProfileActivity.java` file's code:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        CircleImageView mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);
        TextView mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        TextView mEmailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutUser);

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("user_pic");
        mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        mUsername.setText(bundle.getString("userName"));
        mEmailID.setText(bundle.getString("userEmail"));

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Comment: This is too much code. Just post minimum required code relevant to the problem only.

Comment: @ParagKadam I have altered some code. Please have a look.

Comment: Have you successfully fetched image from facebook into your code?

Comment: Then remove the code which access the image from facebook.

Comment: @ParagKadam please answer the question. I can't remove it because it is used in another important piece of code. This will confuse others!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getUserDetailsFromFacebook()` method you have called `new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID)` to get the image. But it seems that before you could fetch the image ,`startActivity(profileIntent)`  probably gets called. 
First be sure that you have fetched the image from facebook before you call `startActivity(profileIntent)`.

**EDIT**

Add this to your `getUserDetailsFromFacebook()` ,

```
b.putString("userName", name);
b.putString("userEmail", email);
profileIntent.putExtras(b);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
profileIntent.putExtra("user_pic", byteArray);

startActivity(profileIntent);
```

Add this to your `ProfileActivity.java` ,

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("user_pic");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: No! I put a handler there so that I can fetch the Image before. It worked and I fetch the image before firing the intent but then also I didn't got the image.

Comment: this code is causing following error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.abc.xyz.SignUpScreen$7.onCompleted(SignUpScreen.java:315)`

Comment: Have you called `new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID)` before writing `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)` ?

Comment: In this case there could be two possibilities - 1) You are not able to retrieve the image from facebook(You can confirm this by taking a `TextView` in your `SignupScreen` activity and show the image in the `TextView`).  2) Your `startActivity()` gets called before `new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID)` gets complete and hence `bmp` has `null` value.

Comment: You should post this code,   `ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
profileIntent.putExtra("user_pic", byteArray);

startActivity(profileIntent) `   in the `onPostExecute` of your asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a right way to pass image from Activity to Activity within same application. You can easily send the path by intent and load it into other Activity.

To save a bitmap in `Activity A`, use

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME); //FILENAME is your defined place to store image
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now you have `FILENAME` global string which is accessible from `Activity B`.
Just load it where its needed.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FILENAME, options);
mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: where is the problem bro? @HammadNasir

Comment: I don't know where the problem actually is.
I have successfully fetched image from facebook but I don't know why it is not getting transferred from one activity to another.

Comment: are u able to see the image when its saved. first save this image into sdcard. Then exit app and see whether its in sdcard or not. If it is there, try to load it in simple activity. If works combine this two task in ur app. that should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me.

**OneActivity.java**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartPage.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        Toast.makeText(StartPage.this, "You have setted this wallpaper for Monday", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        intent.putExtra("pic", byteArray);
                        //intent.putExtra("resourseInt", bm);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity.Java**

```
byte[] byteArray;
Bitmap bmp,
byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("pic");
            bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp);
```